# How to say "to wake up to a world"?

Tags: single-word-request, expression

I was trying to translate the following sentence into German but I could not find a good translation for "to wake up to a world". I decided to go with "zu", and I hope it works.

> Suppose you woke up one morning to a world with no human beings around, no electricity, and no water.
>
> Angenommen, Sie haben eines Morgens zu einer Welt aufgestanden und bemerkt, dass es draußen kein Mensch, keine Elektrizität, kein Wasser gibt.

I also would like to know in which tense these expressions goes well.

Answer (score 8):

> Suppose you woke up one morning to a world with no human beings around, no electricity, and no water.

*Suppose*: Your translation is correct, *angenommen* is the best choice here, but note that it isn't separated with a comma from the rest of the sentence.

*You woke up*: This is conditional type 2 and in German you use the subjunctive II (derived from preterite, as in English it's the simple past) or you can use the paraphrasing with *würde*. That is, "du erwachtest" or "du würdest erwachen".
Your version with "haben" is wrong for two reasons. First, this would imply present perfect and, second, *aufstehen* in present perfect is accompanied by "sein".

*One morning*: Perfect translation! *Eines Morgens*.

*To a world*: The right preposition in German is *in*. You wake up *in einer Welt*.

*With no ...*: This is the same as *without* which, in turn, is translated as *ohne...*

*no human beings around*: While *around* conveys the idea of having those people, well, around you, I would drop that altogether. You can still translate this with *um dich herum* or *in deiner Nähe*.

Note, there's no verb in your English sentence that convey the idea of *bemerken* (*to notice*, *to realize*).

> Angenommen du erwachtest in einer Welt ohne Menschen, Elektrizität und Wasser.
>   Angenommen du würdest in einer Welt ohne Menschen, Elektrizität und Wasser erwachen.

Comment: Good answer. Depending on the context `aufwachen` might fit better than `erwachen`.

Comment: Ich glabube, dass man auch gut Präsens verwenden kann, vgl »Stell dir vor, es **ist** Krieg und niemand **geht** hin.«

Answer (score 2):

A) "wake up **into** a world" – with the German preposition "in" indicating a direction of the action by using accusative case:

> Angenommen, Sie erwachen eines Morgens [in {eine Welt}ᴬᴷᴷ ohne andere
>   Menschen weit und breit, ohne Elektrizität und ohne Wasser].

B) "wake up **in** a world" – "in" indicating location/position by using dative case:

> Angenommen, Sie erwachen eines Morgens [in {einer Welt}ᴰᴬᵀ ohne andere
>   Menschen weit und breit, ohne Elektrizität und ohne Wasser]

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose you woke up one morning to a world with no human beings
>   around, no electricity, and no water.

German:

Angenommen du erwachst eines Morgens, in einer Welt ohne Menschen in deiner Nähe, ohne Elektrizität und ohne Wasser.

Comment: Warum nicht "Angenommen du würdest ... erwachen"?

Comment: That would mean something different, more like "suppose you would wake up .....".

Comment: "Suppose you would wake up" is grammatically nonsense. That's why the sentence contains "woke". That should be translated as "Angenommen du erwachtest..." or as @Iris suggested. — With that being said, I'm afraid your answer needs some improvement anyway since it is merely a translation and that doesn't help at all. How about explaining **why** your translation is the right one?

Comment: @Iris Die Konjunktiv-II-Form ist hier _nicht zwingend_ notwendig, weil das Irreale/Hypothetische der folgenden Aussagen in dem Satz bereits durch die Einleitung  "Angenommen…"  als Kurzform von "Es sei angenommen, …" ausgedrückt ist. Man kann je nach Textform oder engem Satzkontext der Meinung sein, dass der Konjunktiv vorzuziehen ist, und er wäre sicher angemessen bei darauf folgenden Sätzen, die etwa keine Einleitung wie "Angenommen" haben.